# Making a gateway with virtual machines

Tags: linux, networking, nat

I have 2 VMS.

I want the VM#1 to be the gateway of the VM#2.

VM#1 have 2 networks (eth0 - 10.0.2.15 (nat) & eth1 - 192.168.1.1 (internal network)).

VM#2 have 1 network (eth0 - 192.168.1.2 (internal network).

VM#1 can ping http://google.com because of the nat network. But what if I want VM#2 to be able to ping google too?

I'm just begining in that and I'd like to learn how to do it.

Here's what I already done:

VM#1

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

VM#2

```
ip route add default 10.0.2.15 dev eth0
```

Returns me:

> Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "10.0.2.0" is a garbage.

Comment: show routes from vms `ip ro`. Moreover VM#2 does not know about network 10.0.2.0/24, use 192.168.1.1

Comment: On VM2, try running `ip route add default 192.168.1.1`

Comment: @kAlmAcetA
 VM#1 - 
`default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto static`
`10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 1`
`192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1 metric 1`

VM#2 - 
`192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 1`

Comment: @JoelC `Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "192.168.1.1" is a garbage.`

Comment: @Brighter sorry, try `ip route add default via 192.168.1.1`

Comment: @JoelC  thanks, now I got no error but VM#2 still cannot ping http://google.com

Comment: Can it ping 8.8.8.8? If so, then DNS isn't set up properly. Put a line of `nameserver 8.8.8.8` into your `/etc/resolv.conf` file and try again.

Comment: @JoelC I can ping 8.8.8.8 but it does nothing.. (Not like before, it's not an unknown host) but it's doing nothing. 100% packet loss

Comment: Can you ping 10.0.2.15?

Comment: @JoelC Yes.. But why not 8.8.8.8? Can you explain it to me? :/